# Capture messages output from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have below PS script which creates a table. I would like to capture messages output (Command(s) completed successfully.) from sql server. Is there a way to achieve that?

I tried -Verbose switch but that didn't helped.

PS File:

```
$CreateTableFile = "C:\DBScripts\CreateTable.sql"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance xyz -InputFile $CreateTableFile -Database "PSLearning" -Verbose

CreateTable.sql:
CREATE TABLE abc (
  column_1 int,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you want to capture. Everything or just errors.

Errors, you can use try/catch, everything you can use Start-Transcript, or write your own log code, or stuff like print script.

Example:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "update your database set column_name ={expression} where <search_condition>; PRINT 'update successfully';" –Verbose
```

As documented in the Bulit-In Help files …

```
# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Invoke-SqlCmd).Parameters
Get-help -Name Invoke-SqlCmd -Full
Get-help -Name Invoke-SqlCmd -Online
Get-help -Name Invoke-SqlCmd -Examples

Get-help -Name Invoke-SqlCmd -Examples
# -------------------------- EXAMPLE 5 --------------------------
C:\PS>Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "PRINT N'abc'" -Verbose
VERBOSE: abc
# Description
# -----------
# This example uses the PowerShell -Verbose parameter to return the message output of the PRINT command.
```

... or the online ones.

[Invoke-Sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?view=sqlserver-ps&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2017)

> You can display SQL Server message output, such as those that result
>   from the SQL PRINT statement, by specifying the Verbose parameter
>
> Example 5: Run a query and display verbose output

```
PSet-Location "SQLSERVER:\SQL\MyComputer\MainInstance"
Invoke-SqlCmd -Query "PRINT N'abc'" -Verbose
VERBOSE: abc
```

Comment: If I run sql script in ssms i get "Command(s) completed successfully." in messages tab. I want to capture that message. There is no results tab. I tried -Verbose and Start-Transcript but its not returning anything, but i see table is getting created.

Comment: Did you get any success on this ?